# NPM/React - using renamer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-run

Django 2.0, Node.js 8.11.4

I have a djanog project of the format:

My project structre looks like this:

```
reactify/
└── src/
    ├── reactify-ui/
    |   ├── build/
    |   |   └── static/
    |   |       └── js/
    |   |           └── main.3425.js
    |   └── package.json
```

I'm trying to rename the above text `main.3425.js` to `reactify-django.ui.js`. The `3425` could be any number or letter. I'm trying the following code, but it isn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Code:
`"build-rename-js": "renamer --regex --find 'main\\.[^\\.]+\\.js' --replace 'reactify-django.ui.js' build/static/js/*.js",`

Comment: Why you say `number` or `digit`, your mean is "`number` or `letter`", aren't you ?

Comment: yeah, that's what I mean